# How to stop EntityFramework from getting all rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

I tried to create a generic CreateOrUpdate function for EntityFramework where my classes/tables always have an ID field.  Since that data is sent to a webpage and posted back to the server I am totally disconnected from the context and have to use the standard (set.Any / set.FirstOrDefault) way of checking to see if my object already exists.

The method works perfectly in terms of doing its job and creating/updating as required.  But what I have found is that the `db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(whereFunction);` brings back all data from the DB and then performs the `FirstOrDefault` in memory.  I would much prefer this to happen in SQL, but no matter what I have tried I can't get it to work.

Do you have any suggestions on how I might make the FirstOrDefault function translate to proper SQL so that I don't retrieve too much from the DB?

Also, I have tried `First`, `Any` & `Count`, all of which get all of the rows from the DB.

```
public void CreateOrUpdateEntity<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    using (var db = new ProjectContext())
    {
        Func<T, bool> whereFunction = m => m.As<dynamic>().ID == entity.As<dynamic>().ID;
        var firstValue = db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(whereFunction);

        if (firstValue == null)
        {
            db.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            db.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().First(e => e.Entity == entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            db.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().First(e => e.Entity == entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use expression instead of `Func<T, bool>` delegate. Usage of delegate invokes  `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Func<T,TResult>)` method which is executed in memory (and requires all data loaded to client), instead of `Queryable.FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, TResult>>)` which is translated into SQL and executed on server side.

NOTE: I have doubts about whether your delegate can be translated into SQL.

BTW: In order to get entity by id you can use method `Find`:

```
var firstValue = db.Set<T>().Find(entity.As<dynamic>().ID);
```

Comment: I'll have to test out your suggestion, but both of your suggestions make total sense!  Feel a bit dense for not spotting it myself!  I thought it was a failure in EF rather than me! :)  Thanks!

Comment: @Vijay one more thought - if all your entities have ID property, then consider to create base entity class `public abstract class Entity { public int ID { get; set; }}` for them and parametrize your method with `where T: Entity` thus you can avoid dynamic types. Of course, this have sense only if all entities have ID of same type

Comment: Good thinking.  I had originally planned to do it that way, but there are numerous different types.  I guess I could just be less lazy and code up solutions for each one... I'll do some benchmarking when I get time to see whether it's worth it.  I know that dynamics aren't too great and I tend to avoid them where possible...  Thanks again for your advice, much appreciated!